# Json Data Corrupted Error After Updating macOS to 14.2.1 and Xcode to 15.2 with ixguard Toolchain

Tags: json, xcode, toolchain, xcode15, ixguard

After updating my macOS to version 14.2.1 and Xcode to version 15.2, I am encountering an issue when attempting to run my iOS app on a physical iPhone device. The app runs successfully in the simulator, but when deploying to the iPhone, I receive the following error:

dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Unexpected character 'i' around line 1, column 2." UserInfo={NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=1, NSDebugDescription=Unexpected character 'i' around line 1, column 2.})))

run on simulator fine but got issue with physical device with toolchain ixguard

Comment: For Xcode 15, you need to update ixguard to v4.9.7

Answer (score 0):

Quick Fix: Change the ToolChains to Xcode 15.2 or which ever version you have to run the code in Physical device.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).